# Factorials with count-controlled or sentinel loops in java

Tags: java

This is what I am supposed to do:

Write a Java program that will compute the factorial of some numbers n (input from the user, accept only range 1 - 10). For each valid number in input, the output should be the value of n!. Your program should use a loop, to allow the user to input more than one number (count-controlled or sentinel-controlled, your choice)

This is what I have at the moment:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num, result = 1;
    String str;

    System.out.print("Do you want to start? (y/n) ");
    str = console.next();
    System.out.println();

    while(str.charAt(0) == 'y')
    {   
        System.out.print("Enter an integer (1 - 10): ");
        num = console.nextInt();

        if(num < 1 || num > 10)
        {
            System.out.print("NUMBER OUT OF RANGE!");
            num = console.nextInt();

        }
        else
        {
            int i = 2;
            while(i <= num)
            {                   
                result = result * i;

                i++;
            }
            System.out.println(num + "! = " + result);
            System.out.println();

            System.out.print("Do you want to continue? ");
            str = console.next();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

But this is my result:

```
Do you want to start? (y/n) y

Enter an integer (1 - 10): 1
1! = 1

Do you want to continue? y

Enter an integer (1 - 10): 2
2! = 2

Do you want to continue? y

Enter an integer (1 - 10): 3
3! = 12

Do you want to continue? y

Enter an integer (1 - 10): 4
4! = 288
```

I can't get the output to display the right results, that is the only problem I am having with my program. Also, it shows the correct result the first time you are asked to enter an integer, but after that, everything goes wrong

Comment: This is neither count-controlled nor sentinel-controlled.

Comment: You are overwriting the `result` variable for each new number. So you need to set `result = 1;` for each iteration. That is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        String str;

        System.out.print("Do you want to start? (y/n) ");
        str = console.next();
        System.out.println();

        int num, result;
        while (str.charAt(0) == 'y') {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer (1 - 10): ");
            num = console.nextInt();

            while (num < 1 || num > 10) {
                System.out.println("NUMBER OUT OF RANGE!");
                System.out.print("Enter an integer (1 - 10): ");
                num = console.nextInt();
            }

            int i = 2;
            result = 1;
            while (i <= num) {
                result = result * i;
                i++;
            }

            System.out.println(num + "! = " + result);
            System.out.println();

            System.out.print("Do you want to continue? ");
            str = console.next();

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this code works please mark your question as answered,.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `result = 1` inside your outer `while` loop, not before it.  What's happening here is that the numbers you're multiplying are getting multiplied by the result from the previous iteration of the outer `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are not resetting the `result` when you iterate for a new value.
Just reset the result to 1 before you start calculating factorial
e.g. -

`while(str.charAt(0) == 'y')
  {
     result =1;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having a logical error with your if statement. Having a range of 1-10, your if statement should look something like this:

```
if(userInput>0 && userInput<=10);
```

Also, as what David Wallace has stated, you need to re-initialize your variable i back to 1 after your inner "factorial while loop" finishes. In this way, your variable i would always have the starting value of 1 whenever it enters your inner factorial while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would *begin* by creating a lookup table for the valid range of factorials. That might be done iteratively, create a `fact` array and fill it. Something like,

```
int[] fact = new int[10];
int i;
fact[0] = i = 1;
while (i < fact.length) {
    fact[i] = (i + 1) * fact[i - 1];
    i++;
}
```

Then you can use an infinite loop with your `Scanner` (breaking on non-integer input) and the `fact` lookup table like,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number 1-10 for the factorial (or a "
            + "non-number to quit): ");
    if (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
        break;
    }
    i = scan.nextInt();
    if (i < 1 || i > 10) {
        System.out.println("NUMBER OUT OF RANGE!");
        continue;
    }
    System.out.printf("%d! = %d%n", i, fact[i - 1]);
}
```